# On Pages, inserting a graph from Numbers gives a black line at the bottom

Tags: pages, numbers

Notice the black line at the bottom of the graph. When I add another graph after it (its inline), the line moves to the bottom of the next graph so that there is only ever 1 line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whoops! I figured it out. Its really an underline because the inline text was bold and underline. Select the text, and deselect underline and bold.